# Retrieve the contents of each parenthesis nested in a string

Tags: c++

I would like to know a way to retrieve the contents of each parenthesis nested in a string of characters.

Here is a very basic example:

```
([Last group]([Second group]([First group])))
```

To see more clearly:

```
(c(b(a)))
```

From there, I would like to put the content in a vector, here is the schema:

```
[0]: a
[1]: b
[2]: c
```

I implemented several codes, including this one:

```
std::vector<std::string> GetEachParenthesisContent(std::string str) {
            //str = "(c(b(a)))";
            using namespace std;
            int level = 0;
            int Depth = MaxDepth(str);                  // Gets the number of parenthesis groups (in example --> 3)
            vector<string> ret;                         // will be returned
            string tmp;
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
                char curr = str[i];
                switch (curr){
                case '(':
                    if (level < Depth) {
                        ++level;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (level >= Depth)
                        tmp += curr;
                    break;
                case ')':
                    if (level < Depth) {
                        ++level;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (level >= Depth) {
                        tmp += curr;
                        ret.push_back(tmp);
                        tmp.clear();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    tmp += curr;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Result:

```
cba)
)
)
```

This code doesn't work, but it's not for lack of searching on the internet!
I don't think I left on a "bad" path, however, even if my code doesn't work, I think that the principle for arriving at the result must be similar, but obviously better.

I also tried an approach with regular expressions, but I realized that this was not possible.

I therefore ask for your help.

PS: I apologize in advance if I have misunderstood forum, title, content,... I read the rules before posting :)

Comment: 1) This is not a forum. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out, why your code didn't work?

Comment: How come you increase `level` when seeing both `(` and `)`? Shouldn't you be decreasing it at some point?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius: 1) If it's not a forum, what is it? 2) In fact, the program works, but the result is not the expected one.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: I've already tried to decrease `level`, however, there is an infinite loop happening. And now I really don't understand why...

Comment: @AVN 1) You stated that you read through [help], [ask], and taken the [tour] (by stating that you "_read the rules_", so you should know that it is Q&A site, and not a discussion board, nor a forum. 2) If code doesn't output expected output = it outputs the wrong output = it doesn't work (You even stated, that your code doesn't work, in the question, but the comment states that it works.. Which is it?). Again, I will repeat myself, did you step through your code with a debugger, to figure out, why?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius: 1) I have always called this kind of site a "forum". Well, that's all right. Excuse me. 
2) Yes, of course, I use Visual Studio's debugger, the problem (now solved with Killzone Kid's answer), it turned out to be more of an algorithmic problem.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @AVN "_it turned out to be more of an algorithmic problem._" Yet, stepping through the code, with a debugger, would reveal any kinds of problems, that exist in your code, but you should **step through** your code, not just run it with an attached debugger.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius: I don't see the connection. But I'm not gonna stretch the conversation. You probably have to be right, but browsing the code through a debugger won't always solve problems, whatever they are.

Comment: @AVN 1) That's the thing - you aren't _browsing_ the code with a debugger, you are _stepping through_ it, while _investigating_ all the values of the variables, to make sure, that they are the values, that you expect, and if they don't match with your expectations - you can notice it just at the cause of unexpected behavior. 2) I never did say that it will solve code problems. It will never do. But, as I said, it would _reveal_ them. It's up to you to figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but rather an idea how you could approach the problem. I used `std::stack` to go up a level when bracket is opened and down a level when closed. Feel free to modify it further:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

int main() 
{
    std::stack<std::string> st;
    std::string s = "(a(b(c)))";

    for (char const c : s)
    {
        if (c == '(')
        {
            st.push(std::string(&c, 1));
            continue;
        }

        st.top() += c;  

        if (c == ')')
        {
            std::cout << st.top() << std::endl;
            st.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/ok4M3U

```
(c)
(b)
(a)
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer! This perfectly meets my primary need. Turns out my problem seemed more "algorithmic" in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this very easily with a regular expression.

```
std::string str = "(c(b(a)))";
std::smatch match;
std::regex exp(R"(\w+)");

std::stack<std::string> s;

while (std::regex_search(str, match, exp))
{
    s.push(match.str());
    str = match.suffix();
}

while (!s.empty())
{
    std::cout << s.top() << std::endl;
    s.pop();
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. I think I should see my RegEx again.
Thank you very much for all your answers!